# how to use node js buffer with a conversion map

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I am following a tutorial about nodejs. In the tutorial it has this example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const conversionMap = {
  '88': '65',
  '89': '66',
  '90': '67',
};

fs.readFile(__filename, (err, buffer) => {
  let tag = buffer.slice(-4, -1);

  for(let i=0;i < tag.length; i++) {
    tag[i] = conversionMap[tag[i]];
  }

  console.log(buffer.toString());
});

// TAG: XYZ
```

I am pretty sure I know what this example is doing. It is reading the file, then allocating it to a buffer and writing it out. I know that it finds the `TAG` via `slice(-4, -1)` (The tag it 1 up from the bottom and for over). I am just not sure it changes it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it changes each time because it is running a loop and iterating the value of **i**.

*tag* will give you the *buffer.sliced* value and **tag.length** will have that number.

So the **i** value will have an initialization with 0 and then it will run the loop till it reaches the **tag.length**

So if *buffer.slice(-4, -1)* results in "text", then the loop will consider *tag.length* as 4 and the **i** will consider upto 3 (i < tag.length).

So, ***conversionMap*** is a map which does the Key= value mapping.

In this case , *88* is the key and the corresponding value is *65* for it.
But , it is doing the conversion for the *character's decimal value*(which is i ).

You can check that in the ASCII table for your reference.

Comment: I understand that part, the part I do not understand is how the `conversionMap` works, or what the different values of it mean.

Comment: Its not a default one I believe. I think it has been defined somewhere in the  code.

Comment: Yes, it is a variable, It is defined when I say `const conversionMap` I could also say `const fooBar` and it would still work. What I want to know is how it works and what the content of it means (I want to know why `'88': '65', '89': '66', '90': '67', = ABC` when I run the code)

Comment: Yes, I saw it. So what it is doing is . Its a map. IF the Key is '88' then it will give the value as '65' .

Comment: Oh, I see. Now that part of the question makes sense, However I still do not understand how 65 = A.

Comment: YOu need to see the file also. It seems that the conversionMap is converting the values of the i. Thats why

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for explaining that, I am still wondering why 65 = a however

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It is the decimal value of the character, like so: https://www.google.com/search?q=binary+chart&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS731US731&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkiP_JkprTAhUC5yYKHY-ZBzcQ_AUIBigB&biw=1440&bih=826#tbm=isch&q=ascii+table&imgrc=5bIorzxr1dUloM:

Comment: also, I think am going to write my own answer unless you update yours.

Comment: @ZoeCarver: I have modified the answer accordingly. Added the points. Let me know if I have missed something on this context

Comment: Its a nice learning from my side too. Thanks to you too mate @ZoeCarver